# Edit is not working or functioning in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Basically I'm creating a simple register function and I'm stuck at edit.

This is my model:

```
public partial class User
{ 
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="This field is required")]
    public string User_name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public string User_funame { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string User_pass { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [DisplayName("Confirm Password")]
    [Compare("User_pass")]
    public string confirmpass { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public string User_no { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public string User_age { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public string User_email { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my controller for editing:

```
public class UserController:Controller
{
    public ActionResult TestingUserProfile()
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userID"]);

        using (DBModels dc = new DBModels()) 
        {
            if (id == 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            return View(dc.Users.Find(id));
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        using (DBModels db = new DBModels())
        {
            return View(db.Users.Where(x => x.UserId == id).FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, User user)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DBModels db = new DBModels())
            {
                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("TestingUserProfile");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my view. So instead of showing the whole list of users, it will only shows the current logged in user's details.

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.User

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "User Profile";
}

<h2>User Profile</h2>

 <div>

<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayName("User name :")
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User_name)
    </dd>
    <br />
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayName("Full name :")
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User_funame)
    </dd>
    <br />
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayName("Password :")
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User_pass)
    </dd>

    <br />

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayName("Phone Number :")
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User_no)
    </dd>
    <br />
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayName("Age :")
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User_age)
    </dd>
    <br />
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayName("Email :")
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User_email)
    </dd>
    <br />
      </dl>
  </div>
      <p>
           @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditUserProfile", new { id = Model.UserId }) |
           @Html.ActionLink("Back", "SelectCourse")
      </p>
```

And this is the view for editing.

```
          @model WebApplication1.Models.User

         @{
             ViewBag.Title = "EditUserProfile";
          }

              <h2>Edit User Profile</h2>

                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                  {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 
        <div class="form-horizontal">
    
          <hr />
           @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
          @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)

         <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User_name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User_name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User_name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User_funame, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User_funame, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User_funame, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User_pass, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User_pass, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User_pass, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User_no, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User_no, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User_no, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User_age, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User_age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User_age, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User_email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User_email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User_email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

         <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                   <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
         </div>
    </div>
        }

           <div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "TestingUserProfile")
```

So when i try to edit the current logged in user [This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1f8O.png). no error message pop up and it just refresh the page every time I click Save. It just return View() instead of saving into the database. i dont know where is the problem. Please help Thanks !

```
         [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult Edit(int id, User user)
            {
           try
          {
            using (DBModels db = new DBModels())
            {
                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("TestingUserProfile");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message. Can you please give us more information about the problem you are facing

Comment: You need to check the HTML generated. You can do so by using view source option in browser context menu (right click). If possible paste the Edit form HTML the snippet in the question itself.

Comment: Yeah. sorry about that. This is my first time posting this. i edited the question by adding more details about it.

Answer (score 1):

I Think that your View Edit action link should be like below

```
@Html.ActionLink("EditUserProfile","Edit", new { id = Model.UserId })
```

or

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit")/@Model.UserId" >EditUserProfile</a>
```